# How to allow WiX Burn Bundle to be partially uninstalled?

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, burn

Currently I have a WiX/Burn Custom Managed Bootstrapper Application that allows the user to selectively install and uninstall different MsiPackages. That code that handles that looks something like this.

```
private void PlanPackageBegin(object sender, PlanPackageBeginEventArgs args)
{
    var app = applicationViewModels.FirstOrDefault(app => app.PackageID == args.PackageId);
    if (app == null)
    {       
        return;
    }

    switch (Mode)
    {                    
        case InstallMode.Install:
            if (!app.Install)
            {
                e.State = RequestState.None;
            }
            break;
        case InstallMode.Uninstall:
            if (!app.Uninstall)
            {
                e.State = RequestState.None;
            }
            break;
        case InstallMode.Repair:
            if (!app.Repair)
            {
                e.State = RequestState.None;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that if just one application is uninstalled, then the entire Managed Bootstrapper Application is removed from Add/Remove Programs and the install cannot be managed any longer.

How can I force the bundle to stay until all of its packages are removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Modify action when calling Plan and Apply.